# No se ejecutan los nuevos cambios realizados

Tags: flutter, dart

Actualice **flutter**, ejecute la aplicación para probar unos cambios realizados y todo funcionaba bien.

Después de al ejecutar de nuevo la aplicación parece que no guarda los cambios realizados, por lo que si coloco un `print`nuevo, no sale en consola por lo que solo salen los cambios anteriormente realizados. ahora me manda el siguiente error a cada momento.

> VirtualView node must not be the root node.

Si realizo un **Hot Reload** se detiene la aplicación y sale el siguiente error.

```
E/Dart    (25920): ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/object.cc: 3738: error: Unable to use class Library:'package:form_validation/src/providers/productos_provider.dart' Class: ProductosProvider which is not loaded yet.
E/DartVM  (25920): version=2.7.2 (Mon Mar 23 22:11:27 2020 +0100) on "android_arm"
E/DartVM  (25920): thread=25950, isolate=main(0xe83da800)
E/DartVM  (25920):   pc 0xd53eafed fp 0xd40c7da8 /data/app/com.example.form_validation-v7o3n5ntV5GGEqA3fpxVJg==/lib/arm/libflutter.so+0x1321fed
E/DartVM  (25920): -- End of DumpStackTrace
```

Comment: Has limpiado tu proyecto? intenta limpiadolo en la consola, escribe el comando:  con : flutter clean

Comment: @Santiago Use el comando que mencionas y ya funciona bien. aun que sigue apareciendo **VirtualView node must not be the root node.** pero igual es un problema menor a comparación del anterior

Comment: lRespecto ah: " VirtualView node must not be the root node"
es un problema conocido y parece ocurrir
cuando se actualizan las versiones de Flutter superiores a la estable;
Por el momento, recomendaría usar la última versión estable en ejecución, Prueba estos comandos: 
"flutter channel stable"  y 
"flutter upgrade"

Comment: @Santiago intente lo que mencionas pero continua mostrando el mismo mensaje